# Spring jpaTemplate syntax to select from list

Tags: java, spring, list, select, jpa

I feel like a noob trying to figure this one out -

I want to know  the right syntax for the below jpa query to select from a list of numbers. ?

```
List<Long> personIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
personIds.add(1L);
personIds.add(2L);
jpaTemplate.find("select count(*) from Person p where p.id in (?) ",personIds);
```

When I try , I get

```
 "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Long"
```

Comment: Try to cast it with `(Object) personIds`.

Comment: FYI :  `JpaTemplate` has been deprecated. See here ---> [org.springframework.orm.jpa 
Class JpaTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTemplate.html)

Comment: Casting to Object didnt work. I just need to run this one query thats part of existing code , so I do not want to change to a newer implementation since I know I am missing something very trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using EntityManager like so -

```
Query q = jpaTemplate.getEntityManager().find("select count(*) from Person p where p.id in :personIds") ; 
q.setParameter("personIds",personIds); 
q.getResultSet();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your parameter in JPQL without brackets. something like this:

```
List<Long> personIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
personIds.add(1L);
personIds.add(2L);
jpaTemplate.find("select count(*) from Person p where p.id in ?",personIds);
```

I think this should fix your problem.

Comment: It did not work. However, I got around to solve it using EntityManager like so `Query q =  jpaTemplate.getEntityManager().find("select count(*) from Person p where p.id in :personIds") ; q.setParameter("personIds",personIds); q.getResultSet();`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is returning a Long because `count`, and you want to assign that long to a list